# Testnet wallet rpc "not enough money" despite balance being adequate

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, rpc, testnet, payment-integration, api

When I call `get_balance`:

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:2024/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"get_balance","params":{"account_index":2}}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
{
  "id": "0",
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    "balance": 1000000000000000,
    "blocks_to_unlock": 0,
    "multisig_import_needed": false,
    "per_subaddress": [{
      "account_index": 2,
      "address": "BhJQTaLZFYSCpjMdbDS5BjZwKw4BuvP6826VucYUdiV2NdJWc4qVwftgxRQBMzbxxHY8a4B5ahzFdQWijQTzDujA6Tbh8kB",
      "address_index": 0,
      "balance": 1000000000000000,
      "blocks_to_unlock": 0,
      "label": "Default Label",
      "num_unspent_outputs": 103,
      "time_to_unlock": 0,
      "unlocked_balance": 1000000000000000
    }],
    "time_to_unlock": 0,
    "unlocked_balance": 1000000000000000
  }
```

But when I call `transfer_split`:

```
$  curl"http://127.0.0.1:2024/json_rpc" -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"transfer_split","params":{"destinations":[{"amount":999960233000000,"address":"BfmApzUD1erda9SDSjpbULMbTyRUhSpJBMjef5m185NV2EneYinTYfa2HJNwNLj6ePJFZmA3QH9hcG6i7onuu5q7Bycm5cf"}],"mixin":15,"get_tx_key":true,"account_index":2,"subaddr_indices":"","payment_id":"","priority":1,"unlock_time":0,"do_not_relay":false}}'
{
  "error": {
    "code": -17,
    "message": "not enough money"
  },
  "id": 0,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0"
}
```

As is obvious, **1000000000000000 > 999960233000000** so, what do I do to ammend this? Is there some fee I have to take into account?

Comment: Try removing `"priority":1,`

Comment: @jtgrassie , thanks, but why?

Comment: So it uses the default priority and thus lower fee rate.

Comment: @jtgrassie I thought 1 was the lowest priority?

Comment: 0 is the default and lowest.

Comment: @jtgrassie so removing `"priority":1` will dynamically adjust to the amount sent, and the network fees? Or will it just default to the lowest possible fee?

Comment: removing `"priority":1` will cause it to use the default priority (0), which means the fee rate used (and thus total fee), will be lowest. The reason I asked you to try is to determine if the fee being added is the issue.

Comment: @jtgrassie [here](https://github.com/monero-integrations/monerophp/blob/a29052bcebd384f776d4e60a40c10fd435aabd96/src/walletRPC.php#L485C1-L486C1) it says the default priority is 2? 

`public function transfer($amount, ..., $priority = 2, ...)` 

(nevermind that is the library I was using for PHP)

But, I thought `"priority": 0` would fall back on the "default" as is specified [here](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#transfer)

`Accepted Values are: 0-3 for: default, unimportant, normal, elevated, priority.` Not the lowest priority...

Comment: The default I speak of is defined by the [official](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#transfer) Wallet RPC, as used in your question, not some random 3rd party wrapper library. Priority 0 is lowest priority and is the default.

Comment: @jtgrassie Yes I linked that:

"Accepted Values are: 0-3 for: default, unimportant, normal, elevated, priority."

It doesn't say 0 is the lowest just that it is "default". I wasn't sure if setting `"priority"` to `0` defaults to another priority or if 0 is a priority in and of itself.